# Chrome prevents restart during Mac update

Tags: google-chrome, mac, automatic-update

Every time my MBP tries to restart to auto-install an update, Chrome is preventing the restart and therefore the update. To make things worse, the OS closes most or all of my other programs before it blocks on Chrome, which means that I get the worst of both worlds.

Closing Chrome allows me to complete the update, but this is a big hassle to do continually.

Is there a way to either:

1. Allow Chrome to be closed by the OS when doing an update?
2. Stop Mac from closing everything *before* it realizes that it won't be able to do an update?

Two things I don't want to do:
1. Disable automatic updates, because that's super insecure.
2. Close Chrome every night, because realistically that's never going to happen.

Thanks!

Comment: Try: (1) To find out if Chrome is always on the same website when this happens, (2) Delete everything in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/`, restart Chrome and re-setup sync. Backup it first.

Comment: Why do you post a bounty if you don't answer comments?

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been reported on [Google Chrome's forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome) for a while now. For some people uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome allows Chrome to shut down. Also try updating Chrome because you may have an older version of Chrome that still has that bug. This bug is originally [from Chromium around May of 2010](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44321). Answer already discussed in [Ask Different, the Apple Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158684/chrome-wont-quit-mac-yosemite). They recommend you

> Type `sudo killall Google\ Chrome` on the Terminal.
>
> If this does not work, do this:
>   `pgrep -x "Google Chrome"`
>   You will see a number, then type `kill -9 numberhere` where numberhere is the 
>   number that the pgrep command returned.
>
> And to instatly delete the app, no matter if it is open or not, do:
>   `sudo rm -rf /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app`. Then type your password.
>
> The reason you get a permission denied error is because you need root access 
>   do to this, just use sudo on the terminal for this.

#### Resources

- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44321
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158684/chrome-wont-quit-mac-yosemite